# Responsive list style

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, responsive-design, next.js

I am trying to make something like [this](https://codepen.io/esedic/pen/vYOLaNd) in React. I have a dynamic array of locations and want to make it responsive. If the number of locations can't fit in one row then display show more with the number of remaining locations. If I change browser width it should display a responsive array.

```
<section class="thumbnails">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnails__item"><span>Home</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnails__item"><span>Blog</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnails__item"><span>News</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnails__item"><span>Portfolio</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnails__item"><span>Team</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnails__item"><span>Mission</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnails__item"><span>Location</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnails__item"><span>Forum</span></a>
  <div class="thumbnails__count">
    <p class="thumbnails__count-text">
      +<span class="thumbnails__count-value"></span> more items
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thank you

Comment: OK. Do you have a question?

Comment: How to do it? Some advice, maybe some npm package or something.
if you see the link, number of items are hardcoded.